# CSS - make the container center but the text aligned left

Tags: html, css

I have this block with 5 columns using flex:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Emily Thompson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Michael Jackson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Sarah Smith</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>David Johnson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Jennifer Williams</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Jessica Brown</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>John Davis</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Samantha Jones</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Christopher Taylor</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Rachel Anderson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Lauren Johnson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Richard White</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Julia Taylor</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>William Jones</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>James Anderson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Elizabeth Thompson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Matthew Davis</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Rebecca Lee</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Ryan Brown</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Megan Wilson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Aaron Taylor</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Rachel Jackson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>John Brown</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Sarah White</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Catherine Davis</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Olivia Taylor</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Elizabeth Jackson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Benjamin Davis</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Emily Wilson</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
      <strong>Laura Anderson</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my css:

```
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 1024px;
}
.user {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
```

And it looked like this:
[image]

But I want to achieve like this layout. The container will be center, but the text still aligned left, so the space is even. Is this possible?
[image]

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3wk4v6u/

Comment: You do know there is a semantic html element for lists? `<ul>`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using this CSS along with your current HTML

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
}
.user {
  padding: 2px 0;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two, one in flex and another in a grid. Flex is a little bit harder to center because each column of list items are not grouped together in a div.

```
display: flex
```

```css
.list-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.user {
  padding: 2px 0;
  flex: 1 1 20%;
}

strong {
  font-size: .7rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Emily Thompson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Michael Jackson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Sarah Smith</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>David Johnson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Jennifer Williams</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Jessica Brown</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>John Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Samantha Jones</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Christopher Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Rachel Anderson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Lauren Johnson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Richard White</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Julia Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>William Jones</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>James Anderson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Elizabeth Thompson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Matthew Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Rebecca Lee</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Ryan Brown</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Megan Wilson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Aaron Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Rachel Jackson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>John Brown</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Sarah White</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Catherine Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Olivia Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Elizabeth Jackson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Benjamin Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Emily Wilson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Laura Anderson</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
display: grid
```

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / repeat(5, 1fr);
  width: 80%;
  gap: 0 30px;
}

.list-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.user {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Emily Thompson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Michael Jackson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Sarah Smith</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>David Johnson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Jennifer Williams</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Jessica Brown</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>John Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Samantha Jones</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Christopher Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Rachel Anderson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Lauren Johnson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Richard White</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Julia Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>William Jones</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>James Anderson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Elizabeth Thompson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Matthew Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Rebecca Lee</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Ryan Brown</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Megan Wilson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Aaron Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Rachel Jackson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>John Brown</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Sarah White</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Catherine Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Olivia Taylor</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Elizabeth Jackson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Benjamin Davis</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Emily Wilson</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <strong>Laura Anderson</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test with padding:

```
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1024px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.user {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  background: red;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.user strong {
  background: yellow;
  padding-left: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).